# How to write a Debian/rule to copy the file to it's target?

Tags: debian, package, rules

I'm able to create deb . I want to write a debian rule to copy the file to it's target. For eg a script to be copied to init.d and executing it after installation.

Answer (score 2):

> script to be copied to init.d and executing it

Ah. First, be aware that initscripts are handled specially to regular files due to the way the way they require special setup. Take a look at `dh_installinit`.

For normal files requiring installation, take a look at the manpage of `dh_install`.

These `dh_` tools are part of the debhelper suite. It's worth reading the overview of this tool given that the overwhelming majority of Debian packages use this packaging helper.